# Dynamically Populating text boxes from drop down not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get two text boxes to populate when a drop down list has it's value selected (and I want the data in the text boxes to change when the selection is changed without the page reloading), I wrote some code compiling what I have gathered from other questions like this, but for some reason its just not working here is my CS.

```
public partial class UsersFormPage : Page
{
    protected void userddlistedit_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillBoxes(userddlistedit.SelectedValue);
    }

    private void FillBoxes(string HR_ID)
    {
        // Create a new dataset object
        DataSet dt = new DataSet();
        // Create SqlConnection
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SQL2008R2SRV;Initial Catalog=employeetrainingtracking;Integrated Security=True";
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                // Set the connection on the sql command object
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from users where HR_ID='" + HR_ID + "'";
                using (SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    adap.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
        }
        if (dt.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            usernameedit.Text = dt.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Username"].ToString(); //Where column name us the Fields for your Table that you wanted to display in the TextBoxes
            passwordedit.Text = dt.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Password"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the part of my page it affects:

```
  <li class="form-row text-row">
    <label>User:</label>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="userddlistedit" runat="server" CssClass="text-input-dds" DataSourceID="personnelsql" DataTextField="HR_ID" DataValueField="HR_ID" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="userddlistedit_SelectedIndexChanged" />
  </li>
  <li class="form-row text-input-row">
    <label>Username:</label>
    <asp:TextBox name="usernameedit" type="text" class="text-input-lg required" id="usernameedit" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" />                     
  </li>
  <li class="form-row text-input-row">
    <label>Password:</label>
    <asp:TextBox name="passwordedit" type="text" class="text-input-lg required" id="passwordedit" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" />
  </li>
```

I cannot seem to figure out why its not working.

This is the data source for my drop down list:

```
                      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="personnelsql" runat="server" 
                      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:employeetrainingtrackingConnectionString %>" 
                      SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM personnel ORDER BY HR_ID">
                  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: where dropdown is populated, your page load is empty???

Comment: Hello. Thanks for helping.  I edited my question to add the data source for my drop down list.  Is that what you were referring to?

Comment: have you checked by putting break are rows returning ?

Comment: The code that you are running to populate your controls is done at server side? Therefore its inevitable that you have to postback to the server in order to re-bind the page controls. If you wanted this type of functionality it would all have to be done at clientside(using Javascript / JQuery), but even then, your application would have to run server side code to get the data from your database. Its also important to remember that any post back to the server causes the page to Load again and you have to take care of re-binding your controls correctly.

Comment: So, from your point of vie is this code good but it needs a javascript function to update the page?

Comment: Ehsan, sorry I did not answer because I was trying to learn what a break is and were to put it, but no luck, so my answer to your question would be no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what I was missing, so I am posting the code below so people can use it:

Here is the code that goes on the CS page:

```
protected void userddlistedit_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectSQL;
    selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM users ";
    selectSQL += "WHERE HR_ID='" + userddlistedit.SelectedItem.Value + "'";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
    SqlDataReader reader;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();

        usernameedit.Text = reader["Username"].ToString();
        passwordedit.Text = reader["Password"].ToString();
        accessleveledit.SelectedValue = reader["AccessLevel"].ToString();
        reader.Close();
        lblResults.Text = "";
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

This is the code in the actual aspx page, I added two things:
-I added the DropDownExtender
-I added the triggers (after the  but before the  tag

```
<li class="form-row text-row">
                <label>User:</label>
                  <asp:DropDownList ID="userddlistedit" runat="server" CssClass="text-input-dds" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="userddlistedit_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
              </li>
              <li class="form-row text-input-row">
                <label>Username:</label>
                <asp:TextBox name="usernameedit" type="text" class="text-input-lg required" id="usernameedit" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:DropDownExtender ID="ExtenderUserEdit" DropDownControlID="userddlistedit" Enabled="true" TargetControlID="usernameedit" runat="server"></asp:DropDownExtender>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="ValidateUsernameEdit" ControlToValidate="usernameedit" ErrorMessage="Username is required" Display="dynamic" ValidationGroup="EditSection">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
              </li>
              <li class="form-row text-input-row">
                <label>Password:</label>
                <asp:TextBox name="passwordedit" type="text" class="text-input-lg required" id="passwordedit" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="ValidatePasswordEdit" ControlToValidate="passwordedit" ErrorMessage="Password is required" Display="dynamic" ValidationGroup="EditSection">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
              </li>
```

.....

```
    <Triggers>
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="userddlistedit" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
```

I also changed the way I got my data for the drop down list to the following (added in the CS page):

```
private void UsersListDD()
{
    userddlist.Items.Clear();
    userddlistedit.Items.Clear();
    userddlistdelete.Items.Clear();
    string selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM personnel";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
    SqlDataReader reader;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ListItem newItem = new ListItem();
            newItem.Text = reader["FirstName"] + " " + reader["LastName"];
            newItem.Value = reader["HR_ID"].ToString();
            userddlist.Items.Add(newItem);
            userddlistedit.Items.Add(newItem);
            userddlistdelete.Items.Add(newItem);
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Hopefully, this helps someone.